# Attach max file size doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have form in **html**:

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="client-form" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="{{ path('contact_form_message') }}" class="modal-form">
  <div class="row">
     <input title="attachment" type="file" class="pull-left file-inp" multiple name="files">
     <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="52428800" />
     <button href="#" id="submit" class="btn send static-form-button">Send</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**php**:

```
 foreach ($files as $file) 
 {
    if ($file)
    {
        if ($file->getSize() > $this->container->getParameter('attachments_max_size', 52428800 ))
        {
            $message = "File size limit exceeds";
        }
        else
        {
            if(is_uploaded_file($file->getPathName()))
            {
                $fileName = uniqid().'_'.str_replace(' ','_',$file->getPathName().'.'.$file->guessExtension());
                $attachment = $file->move($attachments_dir, $fileName);
                $link = $request->getHost().'/uploads/media/attachments/'.$attachment->getFileName();
                $path = $attachment->getPathName();
            }
            else
            {
                $message = 'Error uploading file';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I have a problem that I can upload files size with max size of 1mb.
 I want 50mb. What I am doing wrong?

P.S
Maybe I must use jQuery for this?

Comment: @sanderbee do you see answer there? I don't

Comment: php.ini can limit uploaded file size. check value of upload_max_filesize

Answer (score 1):

Double check the size limit in your `php.ini` file, maybe that is the restricting factor.

Although this value is supplied in the form the client should never be authoritative, anyone can change this locally.

Comment: That's why i do check in my controller. Yes, in my php.ini max_file_size = 2MB, i change it to 50, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you restart the php daemon? When you change the configuration a restart is required.

Comment: Can you log the $file->getSize() and the `attachments_max_size` parameter? Maybe there is an Mb to MB conversion somewhere.